# Steps to Bypass Siteminder SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

I have a Siteminder SSO enabled website. I need to access a page inside the website without SSO authorization. Could anyone please provide the steps to edit the configuration of my Siteminder policy server to bypass the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new unprotected realm for the resource.  No rule or policy is needed.